# how to solve ldflags error in yocto

Tags: yocto, openembedded, build-system

I am copying already compiled libs to rootfs using yocto recipe(sample.bb).

I got below error

```
QA Issue: No GNU_HASH in the elf binary: 'dev/usr/lib/libnfc_nci_linux.so' [ldflags]
```

below is my recipe `sample.bb`

```
DESCRIPTION = "Adding binaries"  
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
SRC_URI = "file://*"
S = "${WORKDIR}"
do_install(){
        install -d ${D}${libdir}
        cp ${S}/libnfc_nci_linux.so* ${D}${libdir}
}
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "dev-elf"
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "ldflags"
FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/libnfc_nci_linux.so*"
```

Am i missing anything?

Thanks ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add include also using `FILES`. See below line and add to your `sample.bb`

```
FILES_${PN}-dev += "includedir/*"
```

finally it should be like

```
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "dev-elf"
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "ldflags"
INSANE_SKIP_${PN}-dev = "ldflags"  

FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/libnfc_nci_linux.so*"
FILES_${PN}-dev += "includedir/*"
```

Comment: why we need to add FILES_$PN-dev ="includedir" for this error. i also got same problem i have used all vars except "includedir" , can you give clarification please.

Comment: should you not be using `INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "ldflags"`?