# Yocto 4.0.15 encounter error doesn't have GNU_HASH (didn't pass LDFLAGS?) [ldflags]

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

have studied:
https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/qa-checks.html

[didn't pass LDFLAGS? [ldflags]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61473077/didnt-pass-ldflags-ldflags)

[how to solve ldflags error in yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49558653/how-to-solve-ldflags-error-in-yocto)

[Yocto QA issue: test-dev doesn't have GNU_HASH error has never gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76616645/yocto-qa-issue-test-dev-doesnt-have-gnu-hash-error-has-never-gone)

the error is as followings

```
qtporductest-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: File /usr/lib/libftd2xx.so in package qtporductest doesn't have GNU_HASH (didn't pass LDFLAGS?) [ldflags]
```

have tried adding follows in recipe

```
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "ldflags"
INSANE_SKIP_${PN}-dev += "ldflags"
FILES_${PN}-dev += "includedir/*"
```

or

```
File '<file>' in package '<package>' doesn't have GNU_HASH (didn't pass LDFLAGS?) [ldflags]

This indicates that binaries produced when building the recipe have not been linked with the LDFLAGS options provided by the build system. Check to be sure that the LDFLAGS variable is being passed to the linker command. A common workaround for this situation is to pass in LDFLAGS using TARGET_CC_ARCH within the recipe as follows:

TARGET_CC_ARCH += "${LDFLAGS}"
```

or

```
LDFLAGS += "-Wl,--hash-style=gnu"
```

trying all of the example above founds out the same error still happened

and try with

```
INSANE_SKIP:${PN} += "ldflags"
```

although the error did not show again but after studying it might influence other recipe this is not I want

here is my .bb file

```
SUMMARY = "ftdi"
DESCRIPTION = "${SUMMARY}"

LICENSE = "CLOSED"


SRC_URI = " \
        file://libftd2xx.so \
"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "ldflags"


do_install() {
    
    install -d ${D}${libdir}

    
    install -m 0755 libftd2xx.so ${D}${libdir}
    
}
FILES:${PN} += "/usr/lib/libftd2xx.so \"
```

anyone know any better way to fix?

Comment: You can take a look on the Yocto documentation on [prebuilt libraries](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/dev-manual/prebuilt-libraries.html), your case looks like the examples.

Comment: @PierreOlivier Thanks for the reply.I read this before .It use `INSANE_SKIP:${PN} = "ldflags"` to fix the problem but it seems like it will influence  other recipe and this is not I want I have mentioned in the article

Comment: I mean in old version of yocto  `INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "ldflags"` will not influence other recipe which in same layer